# Why display:block on button doesn't make the button full width of the container?

Tags: html, css, sass, display

Why does a button with a display: block doesn't take the full width of the container?
The following code makes the button takes only the width of the content.

MDN definition of block elements:

> "A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the
> full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it
> can)."

```
 &__actions {
      width:800px;

      .btn-primary {
        display: block;
        background-color: #382AE1;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 4px;
        border-radius: 11px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/rihamkharoub/pen/eYGBLOE

Comment: Could you provide an example on CodePen or somewhere similar?

Comment: Please put a working snippet direct into your question rather than on another site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @PyrettaBlaze https://codepen.io/rihamkharoub/pen/eYGBLOE

Comment: @rihankh External code is only acceptable if all relevant code is right in the question itself as well.

Answer (score -4):

You need to set the button `widht: 100%`. Now it can stretch the whole width of the parent element.

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 80px;
  background: blue;
}
button {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-primary">BTN CONTENT</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Like this!

Comment: OP didn't ask for a fix. Check the question, how does code only answer any question starting with *Why...*?